# Picture got zoomed out using javascript getUserMedia with Rear camera

Tags: javascript, video, screenshot

i wanted to take screenshots from a mobilephone rear camera using javascript getUserMedia function the picture got zoomed out.

The image is showed similar to when I took image from 0.5x zoom with my phone rear camera.

Is there a way to always show the video with 1x zoom with  tag and same with the screenshot of that video?

I have tried to use imagecapture from the link https://developer.chrome.com/blog/imagecapture/ but nothing worked.